# Concatenar consulta mysql en php

Tags: php, mysql, array, select, concat

Tengo la siguiente consulta:

select distinct titulo, option from

```
            (select titulo, opcion1 as option from categorias
            inner join productos 
            on categorias.id = productos.categoria 
            where productos.url = '".$urls."' and opcion1 not in (select color.color from color)
            
            union 
            
            select titulo, opcion2 as option from categorias
            inner join productos 
            on categorias.id = productos.categoria 
            where productos.url = '".$urls."' and opcion2 not in (select color.color from color) 
            
            union 
            
            select titulo, opcion3 as option from categorias
            inner join productos 
            on categorias.id = productos.categoria 
            where productos.url = '".$urls."' and opcion3 not in (select color.color from color) 
            
            union 
            
            select titulo, opcion4 as option from categorias
            inner join productos 
            on categorias.id = productos.categoria 
            where productos.url = '".$urls."' and opcion4 not in (select color.color from color))options where option not in (select color.color from color) order by titulo
```

y recibo:

```
Array ( [titulo] => Tecnología [option] => a1 ) 
Array ( [titulo] => Tecnología [option] => a2 ) 
Array ( [titulo] => Tecnología [option] => a3 ) 
Array ( [titulo] => Tecnología [option] => a4 ) 
Array ( [titulo] => Vestuario [option] => b2 ) 
Array ( [titulo] => Vestuario [option] => b3 ) 
Array ( [titulo] => Vestuario [option] => b4 )
```

pero necesito:

Array ( [titulo] => Tecnología [option] => a1,a2,a3,a4 )
Array ( [titulo] => Vestuario [option] => b2,b3,b4 )

por favor su colaboracion.....

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas hacer uso de group by y agrupar por titulo. Te doy un ejemplo de consulta ya que no termino de entender la estructura de las tablas que tenes, si tenes un diagrama o podes compartir la estructura quiza te puedo ayudar un poco mas.

```
select articulo_nombre, group_concat(marca_nombre) marcas 
from articulos a, marcas m 
where a.marca_id = m.marca_id 
group by articulo
```

en la consulta hago un inner join entre las dos tablas y me devuelve una lista de dos columnas donde la primera es el nombre del articulo y en la segunda una lista de marcas separadas por coma para ese articulo.

Vas a poder aplicar esto a la consulta que tenes pero tenes varias cosas que podes optimizar en esa consulta. NOT IN no es muy performante (siempre se puede reemplazar por un join), y el UNION usando las mismas tablas seguro podes dejarlo mas limpio y agil en una sola consulta.

Saludos!